# Count rows > x for many x and many columns?

Tags: r, loops, count, rows, apply

G'day All,

I have a data.frame with multiple columns, with a count corresponding to each column and row. The data looks like the following:

```
  d <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:15,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

I am wanting to count the number of rows which have a value greater than 1, and then I want to repeat this all the way to 15. I then want to do the same thing for every column in the data.frame. So I will end up with data that tells me how many rows have values greater than 0:14 (iteratively) for each column of data.

I can do this one at a time with the following code:

```
  length(which(d[,1]>0))
  length(which(d[,1]>1))
  length(which(d[,1]>2))
  .
  .
  .
  length(which(d[,10]>14))
```

This is really slow, and my real data set is much larger than this so I don't want to have to do it this way. I thought I might be able to do it if as follows:

```
  lrows <- data.frame('cnt' = rep(0:14, 10), 'column' = rep(1:10, each = 15),
               't' = 0)
  lrows$t <- length(which(d[,lrows[,2]]>lrows[,1]))
```

But it doesn't do it iteratively. I have tried a couple of other things unsuccessfully and was hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.

I know this is going to be obvious once it is pointed out but I just can't figure it out, sorry. Thank you for your time and help!

All the best

Comment: `sapply(1:14, function(x) rowSums(d>x))`

Comment: `sapply(1:14, function(i)colSums(d>i))`

Comment: Thanks Khashaa, colSums() did it. I knew it would be incredibly simple!